# Swift: Crashing with transition to other view controller after Camera Access Request

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, notifications, camera

Here's the problem:
There are two UIViewControllers: "WelcomeScreen" and, for example, "FailScreen". 
There is a Camera Access Request on the first one.
User taps "Don't allow" and FailScreen opens. ...And crashes.

Code:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (answer: Bool) in
        print("Camera access request.")
        if answer {
            print("Camera access autorized.")
            // Continue to Notifications Request...
        }
        else {
            print("Camera access denied.")
            self.present(FailureViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Console:

```
Camera access denied.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

- Transition to other ViewController crashes in the same way after Notifications Request (right next to Camera Access Request).
- I'm noob. :)
- I tried present(VC), show(VC), push(VC). Result is the same.
- I'm not using Storyboards. I do everything programmatically.
- Yes, I can show FailScreen on the same ViewController, but what about other options to avoid this error?

Can someone tell me, how to fix it? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

First you should added value for `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`  key in Info.plist  and understand below code

```
 AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (success) in

            if success {
                print("The user granted permission")

            } else {
                print("put up an alert telling the user the camera is not available")

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Camera Error", message: "For some reason, the camera in this device is not accepting your authorization. Check with your device supplier.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })//back on main queue block
            }//if success

        })//requestAccessForMediaType block


    }//switch

} else {//if device has a camera

    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Source not available.", message: "The camera is not available.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

}//if camera is no else

}
```

Comment: "Camera Usage description" key was added before. Problem is not there.

Comment: I got it! Thank You very much!

Comment: Its my pleasure sir.